# Creating relations that makes sense in a many 2 many 2 many format or is the solution badly designed?

Tags: relational-theory, relations

I'm trying to get better at databases and started a hobby project for this.
So this is the flow I'm trying to achieve.

A user can have one or more portfolio
A portfolio belongs to that user
A portfolio consists of assets, both the user's asset and "common" assets, e.g. pulled externally for current prices.

So a portfolio have a look up towards a table that is also a lookup which consist of user asset and common assets.

I have so far only tried to draw this, not implemented it. But my question is if this should be solved as explained/drawn or if it will make the service slow due to too many queries? If so what is a more "proper" way to achieve what I'm trying to do? And having many too many pointed at another many too many, is that ok?

Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated.

Ps. sorry for a bad drawing, it's my first drawing of entities :(

[image: Entities]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your proposed design is that the name of the asset is stored in two different tables.  A fix for this would be to make the `PortfolioAssets` table wider than it is.

I'd add a foreign key to the `CommonAssets` table, and move the `price` and `holdingamount` from the `UserAsset` table to the `PortfolioAssets` table.  Doing that means you only have one place to update a CommonAsset's name and price, which I think is implicitly a goal of yours.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!